# how to rectify my error by using sonar

Tags: android, eclipse, sonarqube

I have installed the sonar plugin for eclipse.

While configuring my application with sonar it shows empty GroupId for project 'HelloWorld' .

What should I have to do to rectify this error?

It has a localhost as **http://localhost:9000**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make a first analysis on the Sonar server for your project ([as explained on our documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Sonar+in+Eclipse)), otherwise you won't be able to associate your project from Eclipse to Sonar.

Comment: i followed that link but articraft and groupid are required?? where do i have to enter them....

Comment: Mylyn is not necessarily required if you don't use the review feature.

Comment: I don't get your question about groupId and artifactId... (you have defined them in your pom.xml or build.xml or sonar-project.properties file in order to have a successful analysis on the Sonar server)

Comment: when i configure my project with sonar its saying  **empty GroupId for project 'Personal Certificates'**

Comment: how to add and what to add pom.xml or build.xml or sonar-project.properties

Comment: Please read carefully our user guide, everything is explained there and I won't repeat it here. You have *first* to [analyse your project](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code) and *then only* associate your project in Sonar Eclipse.

Comment: i did all of these but can u tell me what should we type in artifactid and groupid

Comment: Exactly the same you have put in your pom.xml file to analyse your project on Sonar server.

Comment: this is my pom.xml <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
       <Plugin-Class>org.codehaus.sonar.Personal Certificates</Plugin-Class>
      </manifestEntries>
     </archive>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Comment: when i kept org.apache.maven.plugins, maven-jar-plugin as groupid and artifactid it's saying project 'Personal Certificates' with key 'org.apache.maven.plugins:org.apache.maven.plugins' not found on server

Answer (score 0):

the group id is nothing but the first part of the value mentioned in sonar.projectkey. the second value is the artifactID refer the link below

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Ant+Task